# Is subprocess.Popen actually running or doing anything

Tags: python-2.7

I have am currently running subprocess.Popen as below but in some cases I think it doesn't run properly

```
    bash_command = '/var/www/venv/bin/newrelic-admin run-python manage.py message_listener'
    path_to_output_file = '/tmp/glog.txt'
    myoutput = open(path_to_output_file, 'w+')
    process = subprocess.Popen(bash_command.split(), stdout=myoutput, stderr=myoutput)
    output, error = process.communicate()
```

I get no Python errors, but it is like it hangs before it runs the subprocess.Popen.  I have some logging that shows all is fine before that call, but then nothing happens, it just seems to hang.

If I restart the process, all works fine

I am wondering how I can find out more information on what is happening, or perhaps set a timer or something to check that it is running and if not do something

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, `subprocess.Popen` starts the process, but doesn't do much else. In particular, it doesn't block or wait for the process to be finished (that is the job of the `communicate` function). Can you reproduce this behaviour with a different command so that we can try to reproduce it?

Comment: Thing is the function works most of the time.  Just sometimes it doesn't seem to run, and I don't know whey.  I was just trying to work out of I can find out more information, or at least know that the calling didn't do anything.